# Laravel 5.6 Session is not Persistant

Tags: php, session, persistence, laravel-5.6

It's very strange for me as I have multiple projects on which I am currently working & all are working fine but this one project has issues with sessions. Session data doesn't persist.

I am using `Laravel 5.6` & session drive `file`

**What I tried:**

- Moved `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` from `$middlewareGroups` to `$middleware`
- In `web.php` tried adding `web` middleware & remvoing it as well
- Clear config & cache
- Removed files from `storage\framework\sessions`. BTW files are creating in this directory when a put something in session
- Used both ways of adding data `session(['key'=>'value'])` & `session()->put(['key','value']`
- Used Session Facade as well

No luck With all these. One more thing, After `session()->put()` when I tried to print data on same page from session, it is printed.

This question may seems to be duplicate to you first, but I have did complete search on it & followed instructions in [laravel 5.6 session not persisting when view returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48791496/laravel-5-6-session-not-persisting-when-view-returned) but no luck.

Comment: which OS you are using? Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am using Windows

Answer (score 0):

You are setting session wrongly use session()->put('key', 'value'); And make sure when you are using file driver, the directory where sessions kept is writable.

Also make sure that in you browser cookies are enabled.

For more information about sessions use this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session)

Comment: Note, in PHP sessions are kept in browser of the user by PHPSESSID cookie. If user will disable cookies you cannot save sessions. Therefore always check for that.